# Marker Move on Google Map

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, google-maps

i am new with PHP, i just add Google Map but i have no idea that how to create marker and how to move marker. after that how i will take the longitude and latitude of the maker.
thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you use php and not javascript ? the map is drawn after all client side

Comment: i will use javascript, if you give me suggesion to use javascript other than php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id suggest you use the JavaScript API for Google Maps.

Google has provided code samples that will help get you started. You can access these code samples here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/

As for creating your marker, you can use something like:

```
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
    });

  }

  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

You'll need to know the Lat / Long of where to place the marker.

Comment: i am also using this but i have no idea that how to move marker

Comment: Do you want to move the marker when you click something?

Comment: i have no idea that how to create marker and how to move marker randomly

Comment: The above show's you how to place a marker at a specific Lat / Long. On the example pages you should see how to move the marker after page load.

Comment: i am using this but the marker does not move